# Formatting issues while forwarding html generated email in Outlook

Tags: html, python-3.x, email, outlook, html-email

In python, I have a piece of code, something similar to this.

```
def send_email_report():

message = {Some HTML Syntax with inline styles for building a form}

my_email = MIMEText(message, "html")
my_email["From"] = "XXXX@domain.com"
my_email["To"] = "YYYY@domain.com"
my_email["Subject"] = "Topic : Report Generation"

sender = "xxxx@domain.com"
receivers = ["yyyy@domain.com"]

with SMTP("localhost") as smtp:
    smtp.login(sender, "Email-Password")
    smtp.sendmail(sender, receivers, my_email.as_string())
```

I am able to receive the smtp-email in **outlook**. The formatting looks great, as all the < img > tags are generated perfectly and spacing is awesome.

But when I try to forward the email to another person, the alignments get messed up. Since html tag is built inside the message, only inline CSS is applied.

A few properties such as font color are retained, while majority of the properties like float:right, width of the whole container are not considered. At first, I thought it was because I have mentioned attributes such as width in **px** so I changed from px to % and rem, and added ! important as well, but of no use.

I also have an idea of converting the entire html assigned in message variable to a image and email that(since forwarding an html form as an image will not affect the styling), but I am not sure if it is feasible.

And also I don't want it as an attachment, I can have an html form or the image of the html form in email body. That's fine.

Any suggestions on how to maintain the style property while forwarding the generated email?

Any Help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: There have been a few questions over time for fixing forwarded emails. In short, there is no fix. Outlook rewrites your HTML and then sends it. If you do find a solution for this please let us know.

Comment: Is there any way to convert HTML into Image and display in email body? Then I think outlook cannot change the formatting of the image generated from HTML

Comment: If you do only image email, it can end up as spam.

Comment: There are a few general tricks to getting forwarding to work, like simplifying the code. It's odd that you use floats - Outlook desktop Windows don't support it so email coders don't use that generally (they use tables). If you could supply an example of your HTML we can suggest improvements. Otherwise, a 'view online' link is the other way.

Comment: Please share the code that you're using for the email itself. Outlook in general is a total PITA when building custom HTML emails.